# How to reopen a running .sh script in a new terminal in ubuntu

Tags: linux, sh

I'm running a headless linux server which I've ssh'd into. Now that only gives me 1 terminal to work with, and I can startup a minecraft server with a .sh script. But if I close that ssh terminal, how would I get access to the same .sh script that is still running in the background. Because if I reconnect with ssh again, it opens a fresh terminal.

Comment: `tmux` or `screen` let you start and detach a session and leave it running and result it later. Or, on your local box, you could just open another terminal and `ssh` into your headless box again (no real limit there).  If you put the script into the background, you can always just use `fg` to bring it back to the foreground. Either way, `tmux` is well worth learning, you can turn any terminal into essentially a tabbed terminal with as many open as you like in that single window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki).

When you ssh to the server for the first time, you could start a tmux session:

```bash
tmux
```

And then run your `a.sh`.

When you close the ssh terminal and reconnect with ssh again, you can attach the previous tmux session with:

```bash
tmux a -t 0
```

You could access to the same running `.sh` script